# 'Cannot COPY into nonexistent table' error but table exists in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I setup a table in Redshift and now want to populate it with data from an s3 bucket in a different region. I'm using the COPY command, but I get the error:

```
    "psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: Cannot COPY into nonexistent table customcontent_table"
```

I can't figure out how to fix it since the table clearly already exists. Is there an error in my syntax? My code:

```
    sql = "copy customcontent_table from 'test/2021/03/29/20/20/CustomContent.snappy.parquet' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=AA;aws_secret_access_key=zz' format parquet region 'us-west-2';"
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("begin;")
    cur.execute(sql)
    cur.execute("commit;")
    con.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your reference to the S3 object doesn't look correct.  Should be something like (per AWS docs):

```
copy listing
from 's3://mybucket/data/listings_pipe.txt'
access_key_id '<access-key-id>'
secret_access_key '<secret-access-key'
...;
```

You seem have only the object key but not the s3:// prefix and the bucket name.  I don't think this is the cause of this error but you will want to get it fixed.

My initial thought on why you are getting this error message is because the table is not being found by this session.  Redshift sessions have a concept of "search path" which tells the current session where to look for tables (which schemas).  If this is the case then the easiest solution (or at least the simplest to explain) is just to add the schema of the table to the COPY command:

```
copy schema_name.customcontent_table from ...
```

This will tell Redshift exactly where to find the table.  If you want to set the search path you can read about it here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html

If this isn't the issue then we'll need to dig deeper.